# Problem reading 'channels' with StringOption

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to make a command allowing members to suggest ideas for improvements for the Discord server **and** for a Minecraft server. For them to be clearly separated, I added 2 `StringOption` to the command.

> The following path:
>
> - /`suggestion` [`Minecraft Serveur` or `Discord`] `suggestion`

The selection [`Minecraft Server` or `Discord`] allows you to send the suggestion to the corresponding channel *(`Minecraft Server` in the #suggestion-minecraft channel or `Discord` in the #suggestion-discord channel)*,

This is when the problem begins. It is impossible for the bot to read `channels`.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, AttachmentBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('suggestion')
    .setDescription('Suggère une amélioration pour le serveur Discord ou Minecraft')
    .addStringOption((option) => option
      .setName('plateforme')
      .setDescription('Pour quelle plateforme souhaites-tu faire une suggestion ?')
      .addChoices(
        { name: 'Discord', value: 'discord' },
        { name: `Serveur Minecraft (Saison ${process.env.minecraftSeason})`, value: 'minecraft' }
      )
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) => option
      .setName('suggestion')
      .setDescription('Ta suggestion')
      .setRequired(true)
    ),

  async execute(interaction, message, client) {
    const { options } = interaction;
    const suggestion = options.getString('suggestion');

    if (interaction.options.getString('plateforme') === 'discord') {
      const discordsuggChannel = client.channels.cache.get(process.env.suggestionsServer);
      return discordsuggChannel.send(`DISCORD : ${suggestion}`);

    };
    if (interaction.options.getString('plateforme') === 'minecraft') {
      const mcsuggChannel = client.channels.cache.get(process.env.suggestionsMC);
      return mcsuggChannel.send(`MINECRAFT ${suggestion}`);

    };
  },
};
```

In addition, `channels` can be read in several other commands, which I really don't understand.

Comment: _"It is impossible for the bot to read channels"_ What do you mean by this? Is there any error message?

Comment: Yes, sorry, here it is ``Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')``

Comment: That means `client` is `undefined`. You'll need to check how you call the `execute` method.

Comment: There was a problem with my method of execution, problem solved, thank you!